# How to rename columns by variables using R?

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` like this:

```
dsl.0 dsl.10 dsl.2 dsl.11 dsl.1 dsl.3 dsl.5 dsl.4 dsl.6 dsl.7 dsl.9 dsl.8 dsl.14 dsl.13 dsl.12
1     0      0     0    161     1     0     0   173     1     1     0     0      0    165      3
2     0      0     0    161   161   133     0   173     1     1     0     0      0    165      3
3     0      0     0    161   161   133     0   173     1     1     0     0      0    165      3
4     0      0     0    161   161   133     0   173     1     1     0     0      0    165      3
5     0      0     0    161   161   133     0   173     1     1     0     0      0    165      3
6     0      0     0    161   161   133     0   173     1     1     0     0      0    165      3
```

The names of columns are comprised of `dsl.` and `N`, where `N` is index. The names make no sense, so I want to replace them by their real name.
The relation between names and index of `dsl` is as following:

```
local_index local_name threshold sg_local_index sg_local_name location_id
1               0         A40_1        84              0             A           4
2              10          X201        40              0             A           4
4               2          X501        40              0             A           4
5              11          X202        84              0             A           4
8               1         A40_2        84              0             A           4
12              3          X502        40              0             A           4
23              5            D1        40              3             D           4
27              4           D50        84              3             D           4
28              6           E50        84              4             E           4
29              7            E1        40              4             E           4
39              9         K60_2        84              9             K           4
40              8         K60_1        84              9             K           4
41             14          L0_2        84             10             L           4
42             13           L50        84             10             L           4
46             12          L0_1        40             10             L           4
```

`local_index` are represented by `dsl.N` in the first `data.frame`; I want to change the names of columns in first `data.frame` from `dsl.N` to the real name, like `A40_1,X202`. Is it possible to deal with the names of columns like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try (if `d1` and `d2` are the two datasets)

```
names(d1) <- d2$local_name[match(as.numeric(gsub(".*\\.", "",colnames(d1))),
                                                     d2$local_index)]


head(d1,2)
#  A40_1 X201 X501 X202 A40_2 X502 D1 D50 E50 E1 K60_2 K60_1 L0_2 L50 L0_1
#1     0    0    0  161     1    0  0 173   1  1     0     0    0 165    3
#2     0    0    0  161   161  133  0 173   1  1     0     0    0 165    3
```